# "[will] likely" vs. "[will] probably" in AmEng usage

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, formality, colloquialisms

As far as AmEng goes, can ***likely*** be an acceptable alternate to ***probably*** in the following [OUP quiz](https://elt.oup.com/student/englishfile/upperint/e_minigrammar/nef_upperint_minigrammar03?cc=fr&selLanguage=en)?

> 1. The traffic is terrible [so I'll ***probably*** be late](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22so+I%27ll+likely+be+late%22&biw=543&bih=356&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPhc60zKTLAhVHWRoKHe7OBSgQ_AUICygG) this morning.
> 2. Climate change is *likely* to affect us all by the end of the decade.
> 3. I'll call them if you like, but they aren't *likely* to be in.
> 4. The concert tickets are *likely* to sell out very quickly.
> 5. I'[ll ***probably*** find out](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=721&bih=472&tbm=bks&q=%22%27ll+likely+find+out+if%22&oq=%22%27ll+likely+find+out+if%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...24786.27999.0.28429.5.5.0.0.0.0.315.580.0j2j0j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..2.0.0.J-dtLRv9MfM) if I've passed or not by the end of the day.
> 6. [You've ***probably*** heard this](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22you%27ve+likely+heard+this%22&oq=%22you%27ve+likely+heard+this%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...23596.27344.0.28539.7.7.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..7.0.0.fiElFBR9YGI) joke before, but I'll tell you anyway.

LIKELY

> *adv.* Probably: *They'll likely buy a new car soon*. [AHDEL]
>
> **Usage**:
>
> *Likely* as an adverb is preceded by another, intensifying adverb, as in *it will very likely rain* or *it will most likely rain*. Its use without an intensifier, as in *it will likely rain* is regarded as unacceptable by most users of British English, though it is common in colloquial US English. [Collins]
>
> *likely* meaning “probably” is often preceded by a qualifying word: *The new system will quite likely increase profits*. Some usage guides maintain that such a qualifier must always be present. However, *likely* without the qualifier is standard in all varieties of English: *The new system will likely increase profits*. [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary]
>
> [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/likely)

Comment: _likely_ is vaguer than _probably_. _Likely_ just means there's a high chance of something happening, whereas _probably_ means there's above a 50% chance of something happening.  I usually use _likely_ when comparing the likelihood between two possible outcomes. _The traffic is terrible, so I'll **likely** be late this morning_ is odd because a conclusion should be a probable truth. I feel _likely_ is used outside the comparative context, when there's a chance that falls under 50%.

Comment: I suggest you explain why you think that *likely may or may not be an acceptable alternative to probably in AmE*  in the context you are considering.

Comment: I personally (bearing in mind I'm Scottish) tend to reserve likely for use with infinitives, so I'd say "It's (quite) likely to rain today." but with non-infinitive verbs I'd use probably: "It'll probably rain today." Just an aside from the other side of the pond. :)

Comment: @John Clifford 'likely' is not an adverb in that usage.

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire '... _probably_ means there's above a 50% chance of something happening'. Not as far as AHDEL, Collins, RHK Webster's, Macmillan, ODO ... say. (ODO has **probably**: 'Almost certainly; as far as one knows or can tell'. Even I'd say that's going a bit far, but I wouldn't use  'probably' if I estimated the probability at 51%. English is not maths.

Comment: @Josh61 Because per CED,  "it will likely rain" is regarded as colloquial in AmEng. And so, would answering "likely" instead of "probably" in the quiz above be considered incorrect from the perspective of an American test grader?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'almost certainly' and 'above a 50% chance of something happening' are not easily distinguishable, especially in common conversation outside of maths. Perhaps in maths, people require a greater likelihood than 51% before using _probably_, but not in everyday conversation.  I would definitely call in and tell my boss that I'll probably be late, if I feel that there's a greater than 50% chance of my being late.

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire '... almost certainly' and 'above a 50% chance of something happening' are not easily distinguishable. So if it's rained on 101 out of the last 200 days, it will almost certainly rain tomorrow?  I can't agree with ODO that 'probably' is best defined as 'almost certainly', but I'd want say a 67% probability.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But what does 67% mean exactly? In American law, a prosecutor must show beyond a reasonable doubt that a defendant committed a crime. However, no one knows what reasonable doubt means, while many may believe it should be near certainty (or above 67%), [studies](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01499236) have shown that jurors convict on evidence that amounts to little more than a 50/50 standard. Thus, people are able to distinguish probable truth from improbable truth, but unable to distinguish probable truth from near certainty.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful data on the legal situation, which I'll file somewhere. I've always wondered how I'd avoid a contempt of court charge if I had to argue about the meaning of 'beyond reasonable doubt'. But misuse of the language by various sectors doesn't mean that there isn't a more accurate use. And, according to the dictionaries, few people (remember the panels use research to determine usage) use 'probably' to mean 'having a slightly greater than 50-50 chance' or 'having a greater than 50% chance, meaning say 50.1% - 99.9% chance''.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth wasn't trying to be an ass. My point is, in everyday conversation, people use _probably_ for future predictions with expected values above 50/50, but they usually cannot determine or are unsure of how probable the outcome is beyond 50/50.  _likely_, on the other hand, is used to say there's an appreciable chance of something happening and is vaguer because it could include likelihoods that fall under 50/50.     For near certainty statements (IDK 85%+?), I don't really hear people qualify the statement with _probably_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In examples 2-4, *likely* is a predicate adjective, appearing with auxiliary be: *is likely, are(n't) likely*.
*Probably* is always an adverb, so it can't substitute for a predicate adjective.

That leaves 1, 5, and 6, where *likely* **can** substitute for *probably*. Both are adverbs, and both occur after the first auxiliary verb (*will likely, have likely*), which is normal and common.

However, an auxiliary verb is not necessary; *likely* occurs with simple verbs as well:

- *He likely slipped on the steps and fell.*
- *This likely has nothing to do with it, but ...*

In effect, in American English, *likely* is a 2-syllable adverb complementing a 3-syllable *probably*.

Answer (score 2):

They could be in a round-about way.
Using your examples-

**The traffic is terrible so I'll probably be late this morning.**

The traffic is terrible so I'm likely to be late this morning.

**Climate change is likely to affect us all by the end of the decade.**

Climate change will probably affect us all by the end of the decade.

**I'll call them if you like, but they aren't likely to be in.**

I'll call them if you like, but they probably won't be in.

**The concert tickets are likely to sell out very quickly.**

The concert tickets will probably sell out very quickly.

**I'll probably find out if I've passed or not by the end of the day.**

I'm likely to find out if I've passed or not by the end of the day.

**You've probably heard this joke before, but I'll tell you anyway.**

You're likely to have heard this joke before, but I'll tell you anyway.

Not all of these work well, but all are understandable and make sense.

Answer (score 1):

*"You just walked into the wrong likelihood."*

A diverse question, an even more varied problem, let's start with basics.

Introducing chance to make it whole. (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chance - definition(s) too long to list.)

**Possible and certain are kind of an inseparable pair,** when talking about future events.

- Certainty: Improbable to error, infallible, concrete, perfect knowledge, or the mental state of no doubt. Objectively defined, certainty is total continuity and validity of all foundational inquiry, to the highest degree of precision. Something is certain only if no skepticism can occur.

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certainty

  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certainty_effect
- Certain:

  Google- Able to be firmly relied on to happen or be the case.

  CDO - http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/certain

Modal verbs demonstrate we believe something is certain, probable or possible. Ignoring plausible, as that is the sound of truthiness instead.

The modal verbs, two distinct groups:

- *Classic*: Can, could, may, might, shall, should, will, and would.

  The observed, inferred Chances.
- *Conventionally common*: Going to, need to, must, (+will) have to, etc.

  The passively suffered chances, action-inducing, no guesswork or observation needed.
  These can also be combined with likely, certainly, etc.

Possible/possibility, Impossible/Impossibility:
An option, can happen, regardless of probability/likelihood. There is a chance for it.

- Could indicates present or past(of can).
- Then: Could, might, may fall here. Have form indicates now or past.
- Can, cannot are the general statements.

**Probable/probability, Improbable/improbability**:

*Acting on possible(!).*
Probable is probability with some certainty or chance in the "equation".
Improbable is doubt of probability, same as before.

- Must shows a forcing condition to be, without a doubt, be true, and action is required unconditionally now. Must have (something continuous) is used for near past, and normal past.
- Should is a suggestion - something will be(uncertain, but probable), or is true. Should have, again is a past indicator.
- Shall indicates future, akin to will. (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shall)

**Likely/likelihood, Unlikely/Unlikelihood**:

Likely: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likely, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/likely

As a wiki is open to edit, and merriam-webster is less prone to erroneous edits or NNE tinkering,
I'm going to rely on the first link's definitions, particularly the most bare, simple definition, which is more common in written and spoken English.

- (some adjective) likely, needing a "crutch" to be valid in a sentence.
- very/somewhat/highly (un)likely to rain

**Likelihood**:

*the state or fact of something's being likely; probability*.(http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likelihood)

*In conclusion*:

- Possible is an observed option, a near, or not so close future event.

  This has a "pool"(kiddie pool) of percentage of happening - the likelihood, chance.
  Certainty, Likelihood, possibility pertain to the pool containing something(it exists).

  - Probable is about the percentage of that - A perceived(more than meets the eye?) possibility, fallible, which is less than, but mostly certain.
  - Likely - A possibility is playing in the pool.
  - Chance is a (mostly, or mostly used as) binary outcome observation of possibility. Chancy is very uncommon just because of Chance's nature.
  - Likely sits inbetween, with both being an uncertain qualifier, and a scale of probability percentage indicator. The most versatile.
  - Certain is a concrete binary outcome observation of probability.

Points taken from British Council's English learning article(http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/certain-probable-or-possible)

Then a very good explanation from Robert B. Mercer here:
http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/14222-likely-probably-possibly

A good question on ELL about this:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21191/in-simple-words-what-is-the-difference-between-possible-and-probable

**Finally**:

**AmEng dislikes ambiguity** in certainty, so **would more than likely use probably, or possibly than likely**. *Likely is more "scientific".*

Not mentioning the linguistic ambiguity likely induces in a sentence, as per above explanation. As far as alternates go, unlike synonyms, yes. One could use likely, but probably wouldn't. (I better go into hiding now.)

Answer (score 1):

Likely is more like "there's a good chance something is going to happen"
Probably means more like "it **should** happen and 90% + **will** happen"